# How to create a dynamic sized array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

How can i create a dynamic array?
I tried with that code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int size=0,*value,array[size];
printf("How many array elements do you need?");
scanf_s("%i",&size);
value = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
printf("Your array has now %i elements.Here are the contents:",size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  printf("%i",array[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

How can i realize that? My program(Visual Studio 2013) gives errors.

Comment: Indent your code and add the required ';'s at the end of most statements.

Comment: The array array is initialized as an array with size 0. Note that the dynamic one is pointed by the pointer value. You can use the pointer in the same way as an array to see the values of the dynamic array, just chance in the printf array[i] to value[i]

Comment: Read about `arrays in C` and about `using malloc`.

Comment: And finally, [don't cast the return value of standard allocator functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Also since You are using malloc which allocates dynamic memory, it's good practice to release this memory after You use it, just out on the end. of your program free(value). (Note that the operative system also does this in the end of the execution, but it's a good practice to do it)

Comment: Apparently the Visual Studio 2013 compiler doesn't support [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: By the way, the values You will see, will be totally random, because C doesn't put all the array values in 0

Comment: ok, thx. Can pls someone correct my code? I need an example for learing. thx ;)

Comment: @LuisAlves you mean printf("%i",value[i]);?

Comment: yes it's printf("%i",value[i]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int i, size, *value;
    printf("How many array elements do you need?");
    scanf_s("%i", &size);
    value = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    printf("Your array has now %i elements.Here are the contents:\n", size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%i\n", value[i]);//uninitialize
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer.:) it works! But what means the //uninitialize in the code?

Comment: @user3563783 ; I thought whether there is a meaning by displaying what value is not set.,

Comment: okey, but if i wanna declare a second normal array, how i can set this array to the same size of the dynamic array ( int normal[size]?)

Comment: @user3563783 VLA(Variable-length array : like  `int normal[size]`)  can not be used in MSVC.