# How to enter integers into array with scanf?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer, scanf

```c
int num = 0, k = 0;

scanf("%d %d", &num, &k);

int* A = &num;
    
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &A[i]); //scanf("%d", A+i);
}
```

in that code, I want 4 5 1 3 2 integers put in the array A

input is

```
5 7
4 5 1 3 2
```

but in debug mode, there are

```
    *A  4           int
*(A+1)  5           int
*(A+2)  1           int
*(A+3)  3           int
*(A+4)  -858993460  int
*(A+5)  -858993460  int
```

why  is  the  `*(A+4)`  not 2??????

I tried the num+1, but that is not the ultimate solution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num+1; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no array `A`  in your code. `A` is just a pointer that points to `num`. Where do you expect `A + 1` to point to?

Comment: Please read this [ask]. Your question title is not helpful, it's obvious you have a question.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. During some circumstances, arrays are adjusted ("decay") into a pointer to their first element.

Comment: okok, from now, i just know the difference between that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define an array, you'd do

```
int A[num];
```

Your variable `A` is a pointer to an integer, not an array. You can treat it as an array, as arrays are basically pointers in C. But the memory you're writing from `scanf()` is not 'allocated'.

Comment: that is a VLA, supported in C99 and above (but not C89, and not in Microsoft Compilers)

Comment: `int *A = malloc(num * sizeof(int));` would be correct, but you'd need to provide some explanations.

Comment: to everyone, i want to thanks for your  effort

Comment: `int *const A = malloc(num*sizeof(int));` is *more* correct for the const-pointer.

Comment: i just know 
why is the *(A+4) not 2??????

because 
i pointed integer name with A

integer allocated 4byte
so, sits that the A can point are 4 sits!!

Comment: @CheonSeockBeom On your stack, there are 3 integers (`num, k, i`) and one pointer (`A`). `A` is address of `num`, `(A+1)` is probably address of `k` etc... `(A+4)` is just first place beyond stack, and you should not access that.

Comment: @VojtěchChvojka `*(A+1)` shouldn't accessed either, you don't know where it points.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah, yeah. *Don't do that!* Just giving an explanation of why it was possible to write something there.

Comment: I *really* dislike the VLA recommendation here, especially on a beginner question.
`num` comes from an unsanitized user input and this recommends doing a stack allocation based on it's size. That's just bad practice. Maybe at least use a fixed size array to keep it simple and point to a further resource like this very similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240957/7204912

Comment: @ChrisB VLA is great for simplicity.  Security, sanitizing input, differences between stack and heap, etc, are different (but essential) topics for a later time, ***after*** learning to write code that just *works*.  At this point, OP is trying to get their code to work. More advanced considerations come later.  So I agree with your critique of VLAs, but I think they're acceptable for this point in the poster's programmer journey.

Comment: @abelenky Recommending bad practice without at least acknowledging it in some way seems questionable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* A = &num;
```

There is no array in your code. `A` is a pointer that is initialized with the address of `num`, which is of type `int`.

The code then invokes undefined behaviour on the second iteration of the `for` loop because the memory after `A` doesn't belong to you.

To define an array, you'd write:

```
int A[ /* Number of elements */ ]
```

Answer (score -1):

In C you need to allocate memory for your array, indeed. But the original code might look as woking for the first few elements (in some cases)

C compiler would not warn you about getting out of array bounds and even in runtime your code might not get terminated, so you don't always see your error from simple tests, which exactly happened with the original code

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for `A[1]` to `A[3]`. It only _seems_ to work. It's undefined behaviour. One manifestation of undefined behaviour is "apparently working fine". The `A` pointer points to a single `int` (that is `num`), therefore only `A[0]`  (or the equivalent `*A`) is valid. _"...because declaration of a single pointer to int creates just enough memory"_, no it doesn't create any memory.

Comment: Nevertheless, such behavior is a common trap to fall for

Comment: Yes of course, but you shouldn't write that it works. And as I wrote before: the sentence _"...because declaration of a single pointer to int creates just enough memory"_ is plain wrong. `int num;` allocates memory for exactly one `int`. `A[1]` to `A[3]` also contain garbage.

Comment: In theory, declaration of a pointer allows you to place only one element (here, `A[0]`). Nevertheless, `sizeof(A)` gives me 8 bytes, while `sizeof(num)` gives me only 4 (on my system). Still, one should not rely on "seems to work"